# Exepting member declaration

Tags: kotlin, member, javacv

I tried to use JavaCV with Kotlin, but have a problem in that code

```
import org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber
import org.bytedeco.javacv.CanvasFrame
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame

class Vision {

    var grabber: OpenCVFrameGrabber = OpenCVFrameGrabber(0)
    grabber.start()

    var frame: Frame = grabber.grab()

    var canvasFrame: CanvasFrame = CanvasFrame("Test Title")
    canvasFrame.setCanvasSize( frame.imageWidth, frame.imageHeight )

    while (canvasFrame.isVisible() && (frame = grabber.grab()) != null) = this.canvasFrame.showImage(frame)

}
```

a *grabber.start()* string with *canvasFrame.* is showing a mistake "Expecting member declaration"

Can u help me?

Comment: You need to put that code inside a method

Comment: oh, thanks) i was stupid